# OpenCV translational/rotational displacement between frames?

Tags: c++, opencv, rotation, translation

I am currently researching the use of a low resolution camera facing vertically at the ground (fixed height) to measure the speed (speed of the camera passing over the surface). Using OpenCV 2.1 with C++.

Since the entire background will be constantly moving, translating and/or rotating between consequtive frames, what would be the most suitable method in determining the displacement of the frames in a 'useable value' form? (Function that returns frame displacement?) Then based on the height of the camera and the frame area captured (dimensions of the frame in real world), I would be able to calculate the displacement in the real world based on the frame displacement, then calculating the speed for a measured time interval.

Trying to determine my method of approach or if any example code is available, converting a frame displacement (or displacement of a set of pixels) into a distance displacement based on the height of the camera.

Thanks,
Josh.

Comment: this task is not trivial. Imagine if your ground is without texture, you are lost already. What kind of background do you have? or what for "interest points" do you have?

Comment: Yes there are some obvious limitations that exist (lighting, texture), however for testing i will be ensuring a texture/pattern exists on the surface. The surface could be anything from brickwork, tiles, indoor/outdoor surface,  etc. It's hard to say the exact points of interest i will be using since the surface will change depending on the environment I'm in (limiting factors I would document before/after testing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your knowledge in computer vision. For the start, I would use what opencv can offer. please have a look at [the feature2d module](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/features2d__feature_detection_and_descriptor_extraction.html).

What you need is to first extract feature points (e.g. sift or surf), then use its build in matching algorithms to match points extracted from two frames. Each match will give you some constraints, and you will end up solving a over-saturated Ax=B.

Of course, do your experiments offline, i.e. shooting a video first and then operate on the single images.

UPDATE:

In case of mulit-camera calibration, your goal is to determine the 3D location of each camera, which is exactly what you have. Imagine instead of moving your single camera around, you have as many cameras as the number of images in the video captured by your single camera and you want to know the 3D location of each camera location, which represent the location of each image being taken by your single moving camera.

There is a matrix where you can map any 3D point in the world to a 2D point on your image [see wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_matrix). The camera matrix consists of 2 parts, intrinsic and extrinsic parameters. I (maybe inexactly) referred intrinsic parameter as the internal matrix. The intrinsic parameters consists of static parameters for a single camera (e.g. focal length), while the extrinsic ones consists of the location and rotation of your camera.

Now, once you have the intrinsic parameters of your camera and the matched points, you can then stack a lot of those [projection equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection) on top of each other and solve the system for both the actual 3D location of all your matched points and all the extrinsic parameters.

Comment: Hi Chaiy, once feature points are extracted, would you be familiar with methods for determining the x/y translation and the rotation between frames? Ideally I will be individually calculating the translation and the rotation

Comment: @Josh your task is similar to the problem of multi-camera calibration, where you have images taken from different cameras containing the same object, and the goal is to determine the locations of each cameras. In your case, once you have the internal parameters of your single camera, you can calculate the locations of each capture.

Comment: Yes even though I am using a single camera. Sorry for the questions, I have a C/++ background and I'm slowly reading on OpenCV from some learning books. Are you referring to the internal parameters extracted from a SURF function? (SURF seems to process faster than SIFT). Not sure how this would refer to multi camera calibration since I'm only using one camera?
How could i extract the rotation and translation matrices that occured between frames?

Comment: A result similar to this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238587/using-a-queue-to-keep-translation-and-rotational-matrices-in-opencv?answertab=active#tab-top
outputing the translation and rotation (for example, in pixels and degrees) which i could then calculate for real world based on the camera height

Comment: see my update. No, internal parameters are the intrinsic parameters of your camera. And yes, the goal of your problem is to get the extrinsic parameters of all images in your video.

Comment: Hi Chaiy, unfortunately i have not gone with this method but will be using phase correlation from the Fast Fourier Transform of 2 images to determine translation and rotation (fftw library). Have you had any experience with this to recommend it over the method above? Cheers.

Comment: I am very intrigued by this idea! But no, I don't have any experience on it myself. I guess this might work in a very constrained environment, where the camera movement speed is low in respect to the capture speed. Otherwise the phase cannot be determined.

Answer (score 0):

Given interest points as described above, you can find the translational transformation with opevcv's [findHomography](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findhomography).

Also, if you can assume that transformations will be somewhat small and near-linear, you can just compare image pixels of two consecutive frames to find the best match. With enough downsampling, this doesn't take too long, and from my experience works rather well.

Good luck!